# Effective bandwidth for SMB/SSH file transfers over a wireless/ethernet network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ssh, bandwidth, smb

I have a Windows (7) machine A connected by 802.11n to a router, and from there via Ethernet 100Mbps to a Linux machine B running SMB and SSH services. I'm copying a large file from B to A, using the Windows Explorer (that is, using SMB) or with an SFTP client (e.g. Cygwin's command-line client or WinSCP).

My wireless adapter (identifying as an Edimax EW-7612PIn v2 N300) says: "Signal Strength 76%, Link Quality 100%". My ranges are quite moderate.

Questions:

- What kind of bandwidth can I expected for my transfer to exhibit? Assume no other network usage, or alternatively, some light background activity.
- What factors are limiting the bandwidth? And how can I determine how these factors actually weigh in?
- If I get bandwidths of between 1 Mbytes/sec and 2 Mbytes/sec - what can/should I do to improve them?

Answer (score 1):

Bandwidth depends on:

**hardware**

- end device parameters (cpu,ram,hdd,lan)

for pc limitation connect lan-lan

- wireless adapter

change the adapter and check the speed with the same configuration

- wireless router

connect to another wireless router pc A and B

measure the results on table and change the weak device then again measure on table and then put the devices on their real position and measure again.

usualy wireless adapter and router should be with one brand/technology used by brand
example: ubiquiti usb high power wifi adapter used with linksys wap11 will be pointless

- linksys wap11 is 802.11b
- ubiquiti usb high power wifi adapter use airmax technology used only in ubiquiti devices

**software**

- configuration of the router (radio noise on wifi channel, activated features on the router, etc.)
- configuration of the samba on the linux machine *you can try windows-windows to check if your smb.conf should be changed there are two parameters which you should change depending on the size of transfered files.

also 802.11n doesn't mean 150mb or 300mb.
from my experience in WISP only some devices by mikrotik and ubiquiti can give good speed and link quality.

Comment: I'll try to follow your advice, but we are talking about reasonably-modern computers; and I did try more than one wireless router; and the physical distance is rather modest; and I tried different channels... can it be reasonable to see merely 8-16 Mbits/sec?

Comment: 16 Mbits/sec or 16MB/s?

Comment: 16 Mbits/sec, not MBytes.

Answer (score 0):

It will depend highly on the quality of your wifi connection.
without channel bonding expect a 50% drop of your speed so 150Mbps instead of 300Mbps max if you have a good connections

if you use SMB as protocol add some overhead for SMB to so perferable would be sftp 
depending if your hardware supports it increasing the MTU can be helpfull if you transfer big files.

Comment: 1. See my note about reported signal strength. 2. What's 'channel bonding'?

Comment: Channel bonding is a practice commonly used in IEEE 802.11 implementations in which two adjacent channels within a given frequency band are combined to increase throughput between two or more wireless devices.

Comment: I'm getting so much less than 150Mbps that this is a non-issue for me...